# Is the apostrophe necessary in "the designers' platform feedback group"?

Tags: apostrophe

They're trying to say: It's the designers platform (page) feedback group, by calling it "the designers' platform feedback group". Is that apostrophe necessary? Feels like it's not.

Comment: Imagine if it were a platform for children. How would you write that, as children platform or as children's platform? Notice how much more obvious it is now.

Comment: They put the apostrophe after the s.

Comment: Exactly right. I find that these questions have clearer answers when you look at them this way, by using a plural that doesn't end in *-s* and then considering where you would put what if anything.

Answer (score 1):

That is a plural possessive:

- Singular: designer
- Possessive: designer's
- Plural: designers
- Plural Possessive: designers'

The designers own the platform (or the group?) so the apostrophe indicates possessive.

Is it necessary? That depends on if we want to emphasize ownership.

For example, you can say "The cow's barn" or "The cow barn." The first emphasizes that the cows own the barn and in the second "cow" becomes an adjective describing the type of barn.

Comment: The designers own the platform AND the group.

Comment: I added an example to show whether or not the apostrophe is necessary